# Confusion over doing + with strings and ints

Tags: java, arrays, increment

I am making a program and I am at a part where I am wanting to ask the user to input the score for each judge that there is but when it starts and ask for the first judge it is correct saying "Enter score for judge 01"

but when it goes to the next one it skips 02 and goes straight to 11, then 21.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is the line of code for this area

```
int[] judge = new int[7];


    for(int i = 0; i<judge.length; i++)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter the difficulty score for each judge (0-10)");

        System.out.println("Enter the score for judge" + i+1);
        judge[i]=keyboard.nextInt();
while(score > 0 && score <=10);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 7):

The + operator works from left to right. What you have on the left of the operator is a string, and on the right "i". So concatenation of strings occurs. "i" is converted to a string. Then another + 1 occurs, which is again treated as concatenation of string.

To treat that i+1 as an addition, put it within parentheses.

```
System.out.println("Enter the score for judge" + (i+1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Operator precedence is the key. `(i+1)` should be in parentheses.

Without it, all `+` operations are evaluated from left to right.

In Java a String `+` anything is a String. `"foo"+bar` is just a shorthand for `"foo" + String.valueOf( bar );`.

You can read more on this [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.18.1). It's a bit dull, I admit but it's well worth reading. It will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: Thank you.  It was the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

try this:

System.out.println("Enter the score for judge" + (i+i));

Because if you use any primitive after the + operator without parenthesis with Strings, then it keeps appending them. for example

String = "Guru" + 123 + 5;

is Guru1235

where as

String = "Gurur" + (123 + 5);

ie Guru128

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that in the line

```
System.out.println("Enter the score for judge" + i+1);
```

it is doing string concatenation on the string and i, then concatenating again with 1.

To fix it, put parenthesis around the i+1 like so:

```
System.out.println("Enter the score for judge" + (i+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int[] judge = new int[7];

for(int i = 0; i < judge.length; i++)
{
   System.out.println("Enter the difficulty score for each judge (0-10)");
   System.out.println("Enter the score for judge 0" + (i + 1));

   judge[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
   while (score > 0 && score <= 10);
}
```